# How to create a class that can be accessible throughout a whole Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I expected that if I created a class in the run.py file for a Flask application, it would be accessible to everywhere else in the application.

```
from flaskapp import create_app
from flaskapp.recommendation_system import Recommendation_system

app = create_app()
recommender = Recommendation_system()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I thought that I could access the recommender variable in a routes.py file, for example:
`from flaskapp import recommender`.

> As a result I got this error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'recommender' from 'flaskapp'`.
> I am not 100% sure about how Flask applications work when they are structured as packages and this makes me unsure of how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Is `flaskapp` the name of your top-level module? If `run.py` is a file in the top-level and `flaskapp` is the name of the top-level module, then you meant `from flaskapp.run import recommender`.

Comment: Python doesn't have process-wide global variables, only module level variables. `recommender` is defined in the module `__main__`, not `flaskapp`. It's definitely *not* recommended to import `__main__` from other modules. If other modules aside from your script need access to `recommender`, then it should be defined in a separate module that gets imported by your script and any other module that needs it.